# Change UICollectionView size without viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionView`(Vertical) inside of a `ScrollView` to make it scrollable in both directions.

The user need to select the seat in the room, and the room can have any number of columns and rows, I need to put in order the seats

If I put a value ( 800 for example) of width on the collection view on `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it works

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.collectionView.frame.size;

}
```

The problem is, that I load the seats in a Async task, and If I use

```
self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 113*columns, 113*rows);
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.collectionView.frame.size;
```

after load the seats It doesnt work.

I cant put the size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` because I dont know still how many seats !

How I can do it after load the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`setNeedsLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsLayout) or [layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutIfNeeded) after receiving the data. This will ask the view to update update the layout of subviews, which will trigger a call to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Note that you'll need to update the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method to take into account the new values for `columns` and `rows`.

The difference between the two is that `layoutIfNeeded` has an immediate effect, while `setNeedsLayout` will trigger the re-layout in the next update cycle. Performance-wise `setNeedsLayout` is preferred, at it also coalesces multiple layout invalidations, however depending if you have animations or not, `layoutIfNeeded` might be more preferable.

Comment: I also tried this, but it doesnt work , It let me to scroll the view, but the items still stack in 2 columns

Comment: Did you change the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` implementation to take into account the new `columns` and `rows` values? Or does it use the hardcoded `800` value?